# How to test whether array index is between arbitrary end and start point?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Edit: 4 Years later, I think this was a poorly asked question on my part. I hope it can be useful to someone but I think its a good candidate for removal. Proceed with a grain of salt.

Suppose I have an array, and that some function iterates through a subarray of that array. Furthermore, when if the subarray includes indexes beyond the end of the array, the subarray **resumes at the first index** of array.

E.g., if array length is 50, and indexing starts at 0,

```
48 49 0 1 ...
```

In particular, I'm using JavaScript's Remainder operator to get from end to beginning. `array[i%array.length]`.

While this gets me the continuous set of indexes I want, I also want to do some filtering based on index values, and if they're beyond some point, I want to exclude them. For example, keeping only indexes 'between' 48 and 1; inclusive for the start, exclusive for the end.

What I had been doing was simply filtering on a condition such as `item.index >= idx && item.index < end`, but this obviously doesn't work for array beginning and end.

So, as the title states, how can I efficiently check whether a given index or set of indexes are between these points?

For the purpose of this question, starting point is inclusive, end point is exclusive.

Edit: In response to downvotes, I've clarified the question and added a couple snippets. I'm omitting each detail of the problem for brevity.

Comment: What do you mean by an element being between two other elements?

Comment: The way you state, any point is between any other points, because each point can come later again.

Comment: Wouldn't this create an infinite loop? Perhaps you should explain why this is needed.

Comment: Look into using modulo arithmetic as a starting point. Then it becomes a lot easier to think about

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I added a snippet of the condition I have now.

Comment: @nicael I guess that's the problem, right?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj They way I described the problem it could, but I have some checks for getting the right start and end point so that it doesn't continue indefinitely. I updated my question to try to clarify this.

Comment: Please give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Completeness is more important than brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answers were in the right direction, but didn't quite make it there. My problem was hard to articulate, so I don't blame them.

For future visitors, below is the code that accomplished what I had in mind.

> [Plunkr demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwmsy7w9/21/)

```
/* source array */
var source = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    source.push({ index: i });
}

/* target array */
var target = [];

/* initial index reference in the array; bound between 0 and length-1 */
var index = 0;

/* count of items to be 'displayed', or allocated to the subarray; with index = 0, items 0,1,2,3 will be in the subarray */
var show = 3;

/* init target */

target = source.slice(index,show);

/* specifies count of items to be replaced when updating the subarray */
var increment = 1;

var iterator = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

iterator.forEach(function(item,i) {
    slide(increment);
});

console.log('first index should be at index: ' + iterator.length, 'actual index is: ', target[0].index);
console.log('last index should be at index: ' + (iterator.length + show - 1)%source.length, 'actual index is: ', target[target.length-1].index);

function slide(by) {

      if (!by) {
        by = 1;
      }

      var len = source.length;
      var idx;

      if (index + by < 0) {
        idx = len - Math.abs(by);
      } else if (index + by >= len) {
        idx = by;
      } else {
        idx = index + by;
      }

      var start = idx + show;

      var i;
      var j;

      for (i = idx, j = 0; i < start; i++, j++) {

        var loc = target.indexOf(source[i%len]);

        if (loc >= 0) {
          target[loc] = { index: null };
        }

        target[j] = source[i%len];
      }

      index = (idx) > len ? idx-len : idx;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some other kind of condition, this will be an infinite loop, but here's how it would be done:

```
for (var i = 1; someCondition; i++) {
    if (i >= array.length - 1) {
        i = 1;
    }
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could do something along these lines, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: Do you find `for (var i = 0; condition; i = i >= array.length ? 0 : i + 1)` more elegant? You could also use `i = (i + 1) % array.length` for the incrementing part but that is more math than you need and less performant.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer so that it doesn't iterate over the beginning and end index.

Comment: If you still want to use modulo, but want performance, see [this article](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1946) which shows a faster alternative to modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```
function checkPresence(arr, start, stop, value){
  if (arr.slice(arr.indexOf(start), arr.indexOf(stop)).indexOf(value) != -1)
    return true;
  else return false;
}

var tab = [12, 2, 36, 14, 48, 49, 0, 1];
console.log(checkPresence(tab, 48, 1, 49));
```

Comment: I'm comparing the indexes on an item to the indexes of a source array. You're looking at the `indexOf` the *numbers* 49, 48, and 1...but in my case, these are the indexes, and 1 will never be beyond 49 or 48.

Comment: Could you write your original Array and an exemple of subArray? Because for me, an array is a serie of values reachables by an index.